# Set plugin-values when creating post via REST-API

Tags: plugins, api, facebook, rest-api

I'm using the wordpress REST-API to create posts via a mobile app (currently testing with postman).
To publish my posts to Facebook I'm using the plugin "Facebook Auto Publish" (FBAP) (similar to "Social Media Auto Publish", both from xyzscripts.com)

How can I set the value to publish to Facebook?

In current state every created post is published to Facebook, but I want to have some posts to be published and some only to be created but not published to Facebook.

I've also tried setting different categories for this and only select one category in FBAP. But the post is published, regardless which category I've set.

Anyone knows how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, why it's not working with the categories.
I don't know why, but when creating a post over the API, the post is published before the category is correctly set.

Now, I'm creating drafts (already with correct category). With a second PUT-Request I set the status to "publish" and publish my posts. Now the category is correctly set and only the expected posts are published to Facebook.

Comment: if the behaviour of the rest api is different than the normal admin flow, you should open a bug on wordpress trac